# opencv detects multiple small circles, but not larger one

Tags: c++, opencv

I am very new to OpenCV and I am trying to detect just the penny image, but I am getting a bunch of smaller circles. Can someone tell me what Im doing wrong?

Code from here: https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/master/samples/cpp/houghcircles.cpp

Only things I changed were to make min circle radius 400, and max of circle 0. Because I know the image will be 600x480 so the penny circle must be at least 400.

```
#include "opencv2/imgcodecs.hpp"
#include "opencv2/highgui.hpp"
#include "opencv2/imgproc.hpp"

#include <iostream>

using namespace cv;
using namespace std;

static void help()
{
    cout << "\nThis program demonstrates circle finding with the Hough transform.\n"
            "Usage:\n"
            "./houghcircles <image_name>, Default is ../data/board.jpg\n" << endl;
}

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    cv::CommandLineParser parser(argc, argv,
        "{help h ||}{@image|../data/board.jpg|}"
    );
    if (parser.has("help"))
    {
        help();
        return 0;
    }
    //![load]
    string filename = parser.get<string>("@image");
    Mat img = imread(filename, IMREAD_COLOR);
    if(img.empty())
    {
        help();
        cout << "can not open " << filename << endl;
        return -1;
    }
    //![load]

    //![convert_to_gray]
    Mat gray;
    cvtColor(img, gray, COLOR_BGR2GRAY);
    //![convert_to_gray]

    //![reduce_noise]
    medianBlur(gray, gray, 5);
    //![reduce_noise]

    //![houghcircles]
    vector<Vec3f> circles;
    HoughCircles(gray, circles, HOUGH_GRADIENT, 1,
                 gray.rows/16, // change this value to detect circles with different distances to each other
                 100, 30, 400,0 // change the last two parameters
                                // (min_radius & max_radius) to detect larger circles
                 );
    //![houghcircles]

    //![draw]
    for( size_t i = 0; i < circles.size(); i++ )
    {
        Vec3i c = circles[i];
        circle( img, Point(c[0], c[1]), c[2], Scalar(0,0,255), 3, LINE_AA);
        circle( img, Point(c[0], c[1]), 2, Scalar(0,255,0), 3, LINE_AA);
    }
    //![draw]

    //![display]
    imshow("detected circles", img);
    waitKey();
    //![display]

    return 0;
}
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Looks to me like you're drawing the circles with an offset. Try a simpler test (eg thresholding) on the same image.

Comment: Try setting param1 and param2 in the function to 200 and 100 respectively. Might lead to some more accurate results  http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/doc/tutorials/imgproc/imgtrans/hough_circle/hough_circle.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
HoughCircles(gray, circles, HOUGH_GRADIENT, 1,
             max(gray.cols,gray.rows), // to find only the biggest perfect circle
             100, 100, 0,0 // leave other params as default
```

);

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You've got radius and diameter mixed up. Your minimum radius cannot be 400 if your image is only 600x480. Set your min_radius to 200.

Comment: You are right, but that didn't completely solve my problem